# Incorrect or no user input for multiple questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Here is a program that asks a user for string and int inputs. If someone enters the wrong type on input or no input at all, the program ends with an error. I need to handle the exceptions for every one of the questions that is asked. How do I do this? Do I only need one "while true" line? Can it be in one try block?

Thank you,

Matt

```
customerName = input("Customer Name:\n")
mixName = input("Mix Name:\n") 
L_Citrulline_Mallate = int(input("Amount of L-Citrulline Malate (2:1) per serving(grams):\n"))
Beta_Alanine = int(input("Amount of Beta Alanine per serving(grams):\n"))
Caffeine_Anhydrous = float(input("Amount of Caffeine Anhydrous per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000
Betaine_Anhydrous = int(input("Amount of Betaine Anhydrous per serving(grams):\n"))
Taurine = int(input("Amount of Taurine per serving(grams):\n"))
Creatine_HCL = int(input("Amount of Creatine_HCL per serving(grams):\n"))
L_Theanine = float(input("Amount of L-Theanine per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000
L_Tyrosine = int(input("Amount of L-Tyrosine per serving(grams):\n"))
Sodium_Bicarbonate = float(input("Amount of Sodium_Bicarbonate per serving(milligrams):\n"))/1000

servings = 35
#Mix Total
Mix_Total = float(L_Citrulline_Mallate + Beta_Alanine + Caffeine_Anhydrous + Betaine_Anhydrous + Taurine + Creatine_HCL + L_Theanine + L_Tyrosine + Sodium_Bicarbonate)* servings
#Servings Total
Serving_Total = float(L_Citrulline_Mallate + Beta_Alanine + Caffeine_Anhydrous + Betaine_Anhydrous + Taurine + Creatine_HCL + L_Theanine + L_Tyrosine + Sodium_Bicarbonate)
Flavor_Weight = float(Serving_Total*.25)
Flavor_Weight_Total = float(Flavor_Weight * servings)
Grand_Serving_Total_Weight = float(Flavor_Weight + Serving_Total)
Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)

#while
while (Grand_Weight_Mix_Total > 450):
        servings = servings - 1
        Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)
        print('Servings loop value', servings)

#Flavor weight total calc
Flavor_Weight_Total = float(Flavor_Weight * servings)

#Print 
print (f'Customer: {customerName}')
print (f'Mix Name: {mixName}')
print (f'Servings: {servings}')
print (f'L-Citrulline Malate: {L_Citrulline_Mallate}')
print (f'Beta Alanine: {Beta_Alanine}')
print (f'Caffeine Anhydrous: {Caffeine_Anhydrous}')
print (f'Betaine Anhydrous: {Betaine_Anhydrous}')
print (f'Taurine: {Taurine}')
print (f'Creatine HCL: {Creatine_HCL}')
print (f'L-Theanine: {L_Theanine}')
print (f'L-Tryosine: {L_Tyrosine}')
print (f'Sodium Bicarbonate: {Sodium_Bicarbonate}')
#Calculate total grams needed for each ingredent
Total_L_Citrulline_Mallate = int(L_Citrulline_Mallate * servings)
Total_Beta_Alanine = int(Beta_Alanine * servings)
Total_Caffeine_Anhydrous = float(Caffeine_Anhydrous * servings)
Total_Betaine_Anhydrous = int(Betaine_Anhydrous * servings)
Total_Taurine = int(Taurine * servings)
Total_Creatine_HCL = int(Creatine_HCL * servings)
Total_L_Theanine = float(L_Theanine * servings)
Total_L_Tyrosine = int(L_Tyrosine * servings)
Total_Sodium_Bicarbonate = float(Sodium_Bicarbonate * servings)
#Recalculation Grand_Weight_Total_Mix
Grand_Weight_Mix_Total = float(Grand_Serving_Total_Weight * servings)
Mix_Total = float(L_Citrulline_Mallate + Beta_Alanine + Caffeine_Anhydrous + Betaine_Anhydrous + Taurine + Creatine_HCL + L_Theanine + L_Tyrosine + Sodium_Bicarbonate)* servings
#Print total grams of each ingredient
print("L-Citrulline Mallate Total Grams:", Total_L_Citrulline_Mallate)
print("Beta Alanine Total Grams:", Total_Beta_Alanine)
print("Caffeine Anhydrous Total Grams:", Total_Caffeine_Anhydrous)
print("Betaine Anhydrous Total Grams:", Total_Betaine_Anhydrous)
print("Taurine Total Grams:", Total_Taurine)
print("Creatine HCL Total Grams:", Total_Creatine_HCL)
print("L-Theanine Total Grams:", Total_L_Theanine)
print("L-Tyrosine Total Grams:", Total_L_Tyrosine)
print("Sodium Bicarbonate Total Grams:", Total_Sodium_Bicarbonate)
print("Mix serving weight (flavor not included): ", Serving_Total)
print("Mix total weight: ", Mix_Total)
print("Flavor Serving Weight", Flavor_Weight)
print("Flavor Total Weight", Flavor_Weight_Total)
#Grand_Total_Serving_Weight variable name is printer as 'Serving Weight'
print("Serving Weight", Grand_Serving_Total_Weight)
print("Total Weight", Grand_Weight_Mix_Total)
```

Comment: Since your inputs are all prior to any use of them, I would suggest performing some checks on them before allowing further execution. Verify that the values received are what you expect for each one before moving on to the next. You should be able to do this without any try/except but instead just if/else.

Comment: It is a programming decision you make - whether you'll have exact error messages (`This is a wrong input because...`) or rather a general one (`Something went wrong.`). The former obviously involves various `try/except` blocks while the latter can only consist of only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it would be worth you making a function which will prompt for input, convert to the desired type, and if that fails then issue a message and try again.  You can then call this (instead of `input` directly) for each data item.  Example:

```
def get_input(prompt, type_=str):
    while True:
        try:
            return type_(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Bad input - type {type_.__name__} is needed - try again")

customerName = get_input("Customer Name: ")

L_Citrulline_Mallate = get_input("Amount of L-Citrulline: ", int)

L_Theanine = get_input("Amount of L-Theanine: ", float) / 1000

print(customerName, L_Citrulline_Mallate, L_Theanine)
```

If you also want to reject empty string input, then you can test for this as well. For example:

```
def get_input(prompt, type_=str, allow_empty=False):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if response == "" and not allow_empty:
            print("You must enter something")
            continue
        try:
            return type_(response)
        except ValueError:
            print("Bad input - type {} is needed - try again".format(type_.__name__))


customerName = get_input("Customer Name: ")
comment = get_input("Any comment?: ", allow_empty=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it is only for **`Int`** and **`Float`** type of input. Then this can be achieved with something like this:

```
try:
    num1 = float(input("Enter float"))
    num2 = int(input("Enter Int")) 
    print(num1,num2)
except ValueError:
    print("Hey you have entered the wrong datatype")
```